# Upload files to Amazon S3 with Delphi

Tags: delphi, amazon-s3

using code I found in another topic.  I'm always getting a signature mismatch when authenticating, although accessKeyID and secretAccessKey are verified correct. Also the storage endpoint is correct for the bucket.
Using Delphi 10 Seattle. Possible that the CloudComponents have a problem with the region or (local) time ?

```
Function Amazon_Upload (fileName, bucket, accessKeyID, secretAccessKey : String) : TCallResult;
var
  Service: TAmazonStorageService;
  ConAmazon: TAmazonConnectionInfo;
  info : TCloudResponseInfo;
  upload_stream : TFileStream;
  bytes : TBytes;
begin
  // create file
  upload_stream := TFileStream.Create(fileName,fmOpenRead);
  try
    // filestream to tBytes
    upload_stream.Position := 0;
    SetLength(bytes, upload_stream.Size);
    upload_stream.Write(bytes[0], upload_stream.Size);
    ConAmazon := TAmazonConnectionInfo.Create(nil);
    try
      // amazon connection parameters
      ConAmazon.AccountKey := secretAccessKey;
      ConAmazon.AccountName := accessKeyID;
      ConAmazon.QueueEndpoint := 'queue.amazonaws.com';
      ConAmazon.StorageEndpoint := 's3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com';
      ConAmazon.TableEndpoint := 'sdb.amazonaws.com';
      ConAmazon.UseDefaultEndpoints := False;
      // storage objects
      info := TCloudResponseInfo.Create;
      Service := TAmazonStorageService.Create(ConAmazon);
      try
        // upload document to storage
        Service.UploadObject(Bucket, fileName, bytes, TRUE, nil, nil, amzbaPrivate, info);
        // get results
        Result.Callstatus := info.StatusCode;
        Result.Success := info.StatusCode in [Ord(rrOK),ord(rrCreated),ord(rrNoContent)];
        Result.Response := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(info.StatusMessage);
        If Assigned(OnLog) Then
          FOnlog(info.StatusCode, ConAmazon.StorageEndpoint + #13#10 + bucket + #13#10 + accessKeyID + #13#10 + secretAccessKey, info.StatusMessage, '');
      finally
        info.Free;
        Service.Free;
      end;
    finally
      ConAmazon.Free;
    end;
  finally
    upload_stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I use a very similar code, and I don't have problems with the region. Although the local time needs to be well defined. For example, in Spain we are at the +1 zone time, but Canarias are at the 0 Zone time, a few PCs were set at the spanish +1 zone time and had manually changed the clock 1 hour to match their local hour. Those PCs weren't able to connect to S3, it said that the authentication had expired. When those PCs were set to their correct zone time, then the problems disappeared.

Comment: this is based on your code Marc :-)  Couldnt directly comment on it, not enough repuation..    It doesnt say expired, it says the signature doesnt match, and the signature is calculated based on secretaccesskey, timestamp and region.

Comment: Nice to see that it was of help :-). Please check that your time zone is correctly set.

Comment: time zone is correctly set to Brussels (+1). Any idea what might be the problem ? Still the same error : Forbidden - The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method. (SignatureDoesNotMatch)

Comment: these are the headers generated by the CloudComponents:             host=beta-pom-sender-linkmanage.s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
x-amz-content-sha256=9472d3fa34832b1d3e5a6f8df545ac877cc37728fe08a19c46dddff058757389
x-amz-date=20170809T093809Z
x-amz-storage-class=REDUCED_REDUNDANCY
x-amz-acl=private
Content-Length=9375                                                                                                             Timestamp is 2 hours behind. Not sure how to fix and not sure if this is the root problem cuz only the datepart is used for the signature.

Comment: I'll try your function, my timezone is also +1.

Comment: I get the same error : Forbidden. the request signature does not match ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have modified slightly your code to use a TBytesStream instead of a TFileStream to set the file content on a TBytes buffer. But mostly you have to read the stream, not write it.

Now it doesn't corrupt its content.

```
Function Amazon_Upload (fileName, bucket, accessKeyID, secretAccessKey: String) : TCallResult;
var
  Service: TAmazonStorageService;
  ConAmazon: TAmazonConnectionInfo;
  info : TCloudResponseInfo;
  upload_stream : TBytesStream;
  bytes : TBytes;
begin
  // create file
  upload_stream := TBytesStream.Create;
  upload_stream.LoadFromFile(filename);
  try
    // filestream to tBytes
    upload_stream.Position := 0;
    SetLength(bytes, upload_stream.Size);
    upload_stream.ReadBuffer(bytes, upload_stream.Size);
    ConAmazon := TAmazonConnectionInfo.Create(nil);
    try
      // amazon connection parameters
      ConAmazon.AccountKey := secretAccessKey;
      ConAmazon.AccountName := accessKeyID;
      ConAmazon.QueueEndpoint := 'queue.amazonaws.com';
      ConAmazon.StorageEndpoint := 's3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com';
      ConAmazon.TableEndpoint := 'sdb.amazonaws.com';
      ConAmazon.UseDefaultEndpoints := False;
      // storage objects
      info := TCloudResponseInfo.Create;
      Service := TAmazonStorageService.Create(ConAmazon);
      try
        // upload document to storage
        Service.UploadObject(Bucket, ExtractFileName(fileName), bytes, TRUE, nil, nil, amzbaPrivate, info);
        // get results
        Result.Callstatus := info.StatusCode;
        Result.Success := info.StatusCode in [Ord(rrOK),ord(rrCreated),ord(rrNoContent)];
        Result.Response := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(info.StatusMessage);
        If Assigned(OnLog) Then
          FOnlog(info.StatusCode, ConAmazon.StorageEndpoint + #13#10 + bucket + #13#10 + accessKeyID + #13#10 + secretAccessKey, info.StatusMessage, '');
      finally
        info.Free;
        Service.Free;
      end;
    finally
      ConAmazon.Free;
    end;
  finally
    upload_stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Marc, what a great surprise to find you here. I know the comments section is not for this, but I will take the chance. I learned a lot from you on ClubDelphi, long time ago. My respect for you!

Comment: @jachguate Hi Juan Carlos, I also remember learning a lot from you. It's a very nice surprise to meet again, indeed. I hope you'll stick around here. :)

Answer (score 0):

Running your code I have found the problem. Just change this line :

```
Service.UploadObject(Bucket, fileName, bytes, TRUE, nil, nil, amzbaPrivate, info);
```

By this line :

```
Service.UploadObject(Bucket, ExtractFileName(fileName), bytes, TRUE, nil, nil, amzbaPrivate, info);
```

The local path of your file must not be present on the remote call (I guess it confuses the server, thinking that you are trying to reach a resource you have not permissions to).

Comment: thanks @Marc , I actually found this at the same time. With this code I am able to upload a PDF now, however the uploaded document is corrupt. Getting close but not there yet :-)

Comment: Yes, I see. I have fixed your code and now the uploaded files are correct. Check the new answer.